# JQUERY Slideshow thumbnail to show active state

Tags: jquery, slideshow, thumbnails

I was hoping someone could help me with the 'active' state on my thumbnails, which will show the current background image selected. Please go to www.shahidmirzadesign.co.uk/crystal/ for a test link and the jsfiddle for you to play with is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/AE3Zx/1/

What I would like is a subtle background-color change from white to red.

In advance, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following line in the callback function for the click event

```
$this.parent().css({backgroundColor: '#f1342c'}).siblings('li.thumbs').css({backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'});
```

The above line will select the parent of the clicked image (i.e. the `li` element) change the background color to red, and select the siblings that match the selector (i.e. `li` elements with the class `thumbs`) and change the background color of the selected siblings to white.

See the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AE3Zx/2/)